Response String not printing in HTML same as typescript file
I am using angular code to retrieve values of a string array called response.resultData this works for certain values but when I try to print the values ending with ,  it prints the values missing the part after the comma and space.

Hydrocephalus in infectious and parasitic diseases classified
elsewhere (A00-B94.9, B99+)

is being printed as

Hydrocephalus in infectious and parasitic diseases classified
elsewhere (A00-B94.9



this.problemListService.getVisitWisePomrActive(patientPomr).subscribe(response => {
    if (response != null && Array.isArray(response.resultData) && (response.resultData.length > 0)) {
        problems = response.resultData.map(diagnosis => diagnosis.selectedDisease).join(' ,');
        console.log(problems);
<tr>
    <td colspan="18" style="font-size:11pt !important;padding:1px 5px !important"> Diagnosis :
    </td>
    <td colspan="158"
        style="border-bottom:1px dotted black !important;font-size:11pt !important;padding:1px 5px !important;">
        {{narcoticObj.diagnosis}}</td>
    <td colspan="16" style="font-size:11pt !important;padding:1px 5px !important; text-align: right;">:
        لتشخيص
    </td>
</tr>



Response data as follows
{
    "message": null,
    "messageCode": null,
    "validity": true,
    "resultData": [
        {
            "patientDiagnosisId": null,
            "patientId": 119486,
            "doctorId": 25055,
            "pomrId": 34417,
            "appointmentId": 0,
            "admissionId": 219581,
            "episodeId": null,
            "icdType": "ICD_AM",
            "icdVersion": null,
            "icdSubVersion": "2017",
            "diagnosisType": "2",
            "createdBy": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-03-29 01:29:32",
            "modifiedBy": "26500",
            "modifiedOn": "2022-03-29 07:10:26",
            "approvedBy": null,
            "approvedOn": null,
            "hospitalId": 59,
            "hospitalGroupId": 58,
            "clinicId": 350,
            "selectedIcdCode": "G94.0",
            "selectedDisease": "Hydrocephalus in infectious and parasitic diseases classified elsewhere (A00-B94.9, B99+)",
            "condition": "acute",
            "remarks": null,
            "problemName": "default",
            "assessmentId": null,
            "loginUserId": "26500",
            "location": "{\r\n  \"location1\" : {\r\n    \"displayName\" : \"ER\",\r\n    \"location\": \"ER\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"location2\" : {\r\n    \"displayName\" : \"Patient Dashboard\",\r\n  \"location\": \"PATIENT_DASHBOARD\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
            "isPreviousProblem": false,
            "deletedBy": null,
            "deletedOn": null,
            "deletedRemarks": null,
            "selectedDoctorId": null,
            "resolved": false,
            "active": true
        }
    ],
    "errorList": null }

inspect of the string is looks like follows


Please add an example of what response.resultData looks like

Have you tried inspecting the resulting html with the developer tools of your browser? Is the text cut of in the html source as well? I see no way, the shown snipped can cut anything of that string. Maybe it's just a display issue with for instance the width of the cell

I inspected the HTML and it only shows the cropped string as text.

And the console.log(problems) shows correct output? If yes, how do you set the value of narcoticObj.diagnosis? Again, with the code shown here it's impossible that something is cut of the string. either the data isn't complete from the beginning or it's mangled somewhere else ...

console.log(problems) shows the full string. Do you mean the object in the HTML attached in the question's HTML code.

attached is the inspect screenshot to the question as well.

If problems contains the correct string and the html doesn't, then the issue is caused somewhere else and not in the code you show here ...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

problems = response.resultData.map(diagnosis => diagnosis.selectedDisease).join(', ');

Simply replace ' ,' with ', ' (comma and regular space) in the join method.

this will not resolve the issue but only chanage the concat order
